# What's the preposition when you tell the time spot in the video?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the right preposition when you want to tell the spesific time spot in the video/movie/film?

> The scene is in/on the video at/in the time 1:20:30.

Comment: By the way, the correct spelling is "specific".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time, the preposition is *at*. I would say the sentence as

> The scene is *in* the video *at* 1:20:30.

Note that it doesn't sound very natural to say "the time" in this sentence.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @AleksiFinn Happy to help :) See the [help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) page for what you can do when someone answers your question.